# GFSDK_ShadowLib.win64.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error?

Tags: windows, dll

Try Installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or software vendor for support? It says "Bad Image" on the dialogue title. I just recently put this Pc together and I'm trying tor un GTA V, it's running on windows 7,

Comment: Wait, what is going on? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @MattO'Brien I get this error when I try to run GTA V: GFSDK_ShadowLib.win64.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an error  I have all the latest Windows visual basic C++ libraries so not sure what's up?

Comment: There are no actual questions here, just statements with question marks after them.  Ask a question, (example: "Wait, what is going on?"), and you'll be more likely to get an answer.  Better yet, look at the link @MattO'Brien provided.